# knapsack weight > max size

Tags: algorithm, perl, knapsack-problem

I am currently having a query that results like this

**A,B,C,D, E** = item

*numbers* = weight

1. **A** *15*
2. **B** *23*
3. **C** *10*
4. **D** *8*
5. **E** *88*

   ```
   use Algorithm::Bucketizer;

   my $b = Algorithm::Bucketizer->new( bucketsize => 30);
   for my $i (1..10) {
       $b->add_item($i, 30+$i);
   }

   for my $bucket ($b->buckets()) {
       for my $item ($bucket->items()) {
           print "Bucket ", $bucket->serial(), ": Item $item\n";
       }
       print "\n";
   }
   ```

http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Algorithm-Bucketizer-0.13/Bucketizer.pm

Using this module I am applying the knapsack algorithm to try to distribute the weights of the items to buckets

```
my $bucketizer = Algorithm::Bucketizer->new(bucketsize => $size);
```

The problem is that when the weight is bigger that the size I am searching for that weight gets excluded.

Example:

bucketsize => 30

5. **E** *88* this will get excluded

Is there another algorithm that could possibly fix this situation? Or is there a way to modify this one to not exclude the weight that is bigger than the size?

Is is it possible to adjust it to work like this?

If weight > size then fill only a bucket with that weight

Comment: This question is confusing.  Perhaps I am missing background information.  What output do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to not exclude the weights that are bigger than the bucket size.  
If a weight is bigger than the bucketsize that weight is excluded.
I am trying not to exclude that weight, but fill a bucket with that weight only.

Comment: That doesn't help.  I still have no idea what output you want. What are you trying to solve?  This very much feels like an XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Tip: Avoid using `$b` to avoid conflicts with `sort` and similar subs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the bucket size instead of the actual size for any items over the bucket size.

```
use Algorithm::Bucketizer qw( );
use List::Util            qw( min );

my @items = ...;
my $bucket_size = 30;

my $bzer = Algorithm::Bucketizer->new( bucketsize => $bucket_size );
for my $i (0..$#items) {
    $bzer->add_item( $i => min($items[$i], $bucket_size) );
}

my @bucketed_items = map { [ $bucket->items() ] } $bzer->buckets();
```

Alternatively, since you know oversized values will take up an entire bucket, filter them out and add them back to the results.

```
use Algorithm::Bucketizer qw( );

my @items = ...;
my $bucket_size = 30;

my $bzer = Algorithm::Bucketizer->new( bucketsize => $bucket_size );
my @bucketed_items;
for my $i (0..$#items) {
    if ($items[$i] >= $bucket_size) {
        push @bucketed_items, [ $i ];
    } else {
        $bzer->add_item( $i => $items[$i] );
    }
}

push @bucketed_items, map { [ $bucket->items() ] } $bzer->buckets();
```

Comment: (The second solution is the same as Prune's.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you're stuck.  You merely add a pre-processing step to the existing algorithm.  You make a single pass over the weights.  When you find one `>= bucketsize`, simply fill one bucket with that weight.  Then remove that weight and the bucket from the problem set and continue as usual.

In your example above, you would start with

```
bucket[0] = 88
weights = [15, 23, 10, 8]
```

Continue with your usual solution, appending the 88-kg bucket after you return.